# Save the value in UIpickerview once done editing

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uipickerview

I need help with number 4.

1. Select the `UITextField` and show `UIPickerView` (CHECK)
2. Select the value in `UIPickerView` and display in `UITextfield` (CHECK)
3. Click on the screen and move focus from `UITextField` and `UIPickerView` disappear (CHECK)
4. Click back on the `UITextfield` and it displays the selected value in `UITextField` but the `UIPickerView` is back to starting point (row 0).

Here is my code:

```
 @IBAction func textFieldEditing(sender: UITextField){
    var numberPicker:UIPickerView = UIPickerView()
    var row:Int = 0
    numberPicker.delegate = self
    desiredText?.inputView = numberPicker
    numberPicker.selectRow(79, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
    //desiredText?.text = pickOption[79]
}


func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
    return pickOption.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return pickOption[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){
    desiredText!.text = pickOption[row]
}
```

Comment: You hardcode the selection of row 79 when you create the picker view. Instead, select the row representing the current value in the text field.

Comment: The reason why I did that is because I want to display the user that row even before users beginnings editing. Even If I take it out and leave it blank for user when they start, How would I set the the row representing the current value in the text field. I have tried few things and googled around. Couldn't find an answer.

Comment: I don't know Swift well enough to write an answer. But basically you find the index of `desiredText.text` in the `pickOption` array. Use that index to select the picker view row.

Comment: That is where I am having hard time. I was also on the same path but couldn't figure out the code